# ValueError: Input must be a rank-1 array. when using scipy.signal.ss2zpk

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, signal-processing

I'm working with `scipy.signal` and i'm trying to convert a State Space representation to a ZeroPoleGain representation using `scipy.signal.ss2zpk` because i want to change the gain in order to control the system. I'm doing this:

```
A = np.array([[0, 1, 0, 0],
              [0, 0, (-3*m*g*l/(4*M + m)), 0], 
              [0, 0, 0, 1],
              [0, 0, 3*(M+m)*g/((4*M + m)*l), 0]])

B = np.array([[0],
              [4/(4*M + m)],
              [0],
              [-3*F/((4*M + m)*l)]])

C = np.array([
              [1,0,0,0],
              [0,0,0,0],
              [0,0,1,0],
              [0,0,0,0]
])

D = np.array([
              [0],
              [0],
              [0],
              [0]
])
sys_zpk = signal.ss2zpk(A,B,C,D)
```

But i'm getting this ValueError:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-64-5eec82e63217> in <module>()
----> 1 sys_zpk = signal.ss2zpk(A,B,C,D)

2 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/scipy/signal/lti_conversion.py in ss2zpk(A, B, C, D, input)
    332 
    333     """
--> 334     return tf2zpk(*ss2tf(A, B, C, D, input=input))
    335 
    336 

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/scipy/signal/filter_design.py in tf2zpk(b, a)
   1067     k = b[0]
   1068     b /= b[0]
-> 1069     z = roots(b)
   1070     p = roots(a)
   1071     return z, p, k

<__array_function__ internals> in roots(*args, **kwargs)

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/numpy/lib/polynomial.py in roots(p)
    219     p = atleast_1d(p)
    220     if p.ndim != 1:
--> 221         raise ValueError("Input must be a rank-1 array.")
    222 
    223     # find non-zero array entries

ValueError: Input must be a rank-1 array.
```

Anyone can help me?

Comment: what are your values for `M, m, g, l`?

Comment: I'm using g = 9.8,  M = 1., m = .1 , l = .5, F = 10